# Declaring fixed length array with initialized values

Tags: arrays, delphi

Can someone please tell me why the compiler wont allow the following code:

```
  TNumbers = class
  private
    var NumbersPriv : array[1..7] of integer = (1,2,4,5,6,7,2);
  public
    var NumbersPub : array[1..7] of integer = (1,2,4,5,6,7,2);
  end;
```

But the following code will compile without errors:

```
var // global variables
  Numbers : array[1..7] of integer = (1,2,4,5,6,7,2);
```

Comment: Because the language allows initialisation of global variables but not fields. BTW I've had to guess the context for some of these excerpts because context has been removed. I guessed that the first excerpt is from a class type declaration and the second is a global variable declaration. Don't remove this context when posting so that guesswork is. It required.

Comment: * The declaration "var" is not used in the object.
* An object field is initialized in the constructor

Comment: @USauter: The fields of an object are always initialised to zero before the ctor runs. Global variables are also initialised to zero (by default), but syntactically also allow a non-default initial value, as pointed out by David.

Comment: @USauter var can be used in a class declaration like that and there are plenty of good reasons to do so

Comment: @Andreas globals are only default initialised if they are not explicitly initialised. In the code above the global is not zero initialised.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : guesswork was correct and sorry . Now that you say it like that it makes sense .